# errors In scikit-image metrics on 1D array

Tags: scikit-image

I am trying to explore different [skimage metrics](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html) on 1D array . I have two array `noisy signal` and `clean signal`. Code snippet is given below .

```
import numpy as np 
import skimage.metrics as M
clean_signal = np.arange(1,10, .1)
noisy_signal = clean_signal+np.random.normal(0,1,90)
M.mean_squared_error(noisy_signal, clean_signal)
M.peak_signal_noise_ratio(noisy_signal, clean_signal)
M.variation_of_information(noisy_signal, clean_signal)
```

Metrics which are given in code snippet are giving following errors .
For `adapted_rand_error` and `variation_of_information` I get Error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

and for `peak_signal_noise_ratio` I get error

```
ValueError: image_true has intensity values outside the range expected for its data type. Please manually specify the data_range.
```

I would like to know how to fix these errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.variation_of_information), the function `skimage.metrics.variation_of_information` only accepts integer images:

> `skimage.metrics.variation_of_information(image0=None, image1=None, *, table=None, ignore_labels=())`
> (...)
> **Parameters**:
> `image0`, `image1`
> ndarray of **int** Label images / segmentations, must have same shape.

The same is true for `adapted_rand_error`

For your other function, the error message is already telling you much. If we check the documentation again, you can see that the call signature is

> `skimage.metrics.peak_signal_noise_ratio(image_true, image_test, *, data_range=None)`

You are supposed to specify the `data_range` parameter, in your case `(min(noisy_signal ),max(noisy_signal ))` should do

Comment: yes I tried this . But it gives errors  for negative int.  I want to manipulate negative  int  in such a way that it  does not change the objective/meaning  of metric.

Comment: sorry, but I can only answer the question that you asked. If you have already fixed the error posted in your question and got a new error, then please edit your question or ask a new one

Comment: For the negative ìnt` values: If you add a constant integer to all elements in both arrays, then the metric does not change. make that integer large enough so that you only have positive integers